# Consultar base de datos desde la memoria interna

Tags: android, sql, base-de-datos

estoy trabajando en una app y necesito utilizar una BD SQlite(ya creada) desde la memoria interna del movil. He buscado y no encuentro, ya se como seria crear la BD desde cero en  la propia app o copiar una BD a la carpeta assets y de ahi trabajar con ella, pero no logro encontrar nada sobre como utilizar la BD ya creada desde la memoria del telefono...o sea aplicacion por un lado y BD en /scard/AplicacionX/basedatosx.bd/

Comment: Pues es básicamente el mismo proceso que ponerla en `assets` añadiéndole el paso de que cuando la app se ejecuta has de comprobar si ya está en la carpeta de la memoria externa que le indiques y si no está copiarla de `assets` a esa carpeta

Comment: si ya eso lo se hacer, pero yo no quiero tener q poner la BD en la carpeta assets en ningun momento, sino q desde el principio este en la memoria del movil y desde alli consultarla

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que la app descargue la base de datos a la carpeta desde algún servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con esta clase resolvi el problema

```
public class MiBaseDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Ruta por defecto de las bases de datos en el sistema Android
    private static String DB_PATH = "/FelixDroyd/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "etecsa.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    //contructor con referencia a la memoria interna del movil

   // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() hace referencia a /storage/emulated/0
   //    "/storage/external_SD" este e pa la externa

    public MiBaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, "/storage/external_SD" +DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

    }
    /**
     * Comprueba si la base de datos existe
     *
     * @return true si existe, false si no existe
     */
   public boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            String myPath = "/storage/external_SD" +DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
//si llegamos aqui es porque la base de datos no existe todavía.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Persona recuperarPERSONA(String numero) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"number","name","address","identification","province"};
        Cursor c = db.query("movil", valores_recuperar, "number=" +"'"+ numero+"'",
                null, null, null, null, null);
        Persona cuerpo = null;
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

           cuerpo = new Persona(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3), c.getInt(4));
            db.close();
            c.close();
        }else{
          cuerpo = new Persona(" "," ", " ", " ", 1);
        }

        return cuerpo;
    }
}
```

y con el metodo recuperarPERSONA() ago las consultas....

Comment: Si esto resolvió tu problema, márcalo como respuesta aceptada para que otros sepan que la pregunta fue resuelta :)